# Vertica INSERT speed highly depends on server load

Tags: insert, vertica

I faced a problem with very slow `INSERT`s in `Vertica DB`.
I made such test: create empty table with no projections and start inserting in it in batch, using

```
> INSERT INTO table
SELECT 111,222,333 UNION ALL
SELECT 444,555,666 UNION ALL
SELECT 777,888,999;
```

1000 rows in one query.

On idle server one query runs about 2sec and it's alright, but then I start generating some load making `SELECT`s (not very big load though, about 10 LA on 32 core server) and `INSERT`s start to performs 20x slower ( 40-60 sec each 1000 rows `INSERT`). It's too slow for my conditions. What can I do besides copying files to Vertica server and make COPY which seems to perform good, but too complicated?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be surprised that a load takes longer when there's more resource usage. However, there's probably a simple explanation for your poor performance. I would examine the following:

1. The `INSERT` with `UNION ALL`s is highly suspicious. Is the load more than 100MB? If yes, use `COPY`.
2. Are the projections optimized for load?
3. Is the query profiled and no locks being used on the target table?
4. Most importantly, is the load local? From a client across a wide network? Test a load from a local file as a benchmark.

Your "1000 rows" isn't helpful because your row can be 10MB wide, or you could be loading `JSON`, loading `LONG VARCHAR`, etc. An actual load size is more valuable. On a typical DL380 Gen2, you should see around 350GB/HR/node.

Comment: Even if the load is under 100MB, I would still recommend using [`COPY`](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/COPY/COPY.htm).  I think what @andylens just needs to know is that he can just use [`COPY LOCAL`](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/COPY/COPYLOCAL.htm) or `COPY FROM STDIN`.

Comment: @woot I wouldn't use COPY for a single row. We'll have to agree to disagree.